# is there a way to keep a list inside of a list of dictionaries from converting to a string when i'm writing to a csv file ,while using Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having a problem when I'm writing `dictir=[]`variable to a CSV file, so inside the `dictir=[]` list there are two dictionaries and each of the two dictionaries contains a list with the key `["cities"]`, every time I write the list `dictir=[]` on the csv file for some reason the list with the key `["cities"]` is converted to a string on the CSV file, is the problem on how I'm writing the list? or the whole code? any help will be great

how it's written on the `data.csv` file

```
,countrey,cities,time_visited
0,france,"['paris', 'lyon']",4
1,germany,"['Munich', 'Frankfurt']",9
```

how i want the `data.csv` file to look like , without `""` on the france and germany list

```
,countrey,cities,time_visited
0,france,['paris', 'lyon'],4
1,germany,['Munich', 'Frankfurt'],9
```

here is the code i used to write on the csv file

```
import pandas 
import csv
dictir=[

    {"countrey":"france",
    "cities":["paris","lyon"],
    "time_visited":4}
    ,
    {"countrey":"germany",
    "cities":["Munich","Frankfurt"],
    "time_visited":9}
]


df = pandas.DataFrame(dictir) 
to_csv_file=df.to_csv ("data.csv")
```

Comment: The quotes are there so the csv is actually a `csv`: the comma separates the columns. In `0,france,['paris', 'lyon'],4` there're 5 columns, not 4: column 3 has `['paris'` and column 4, `'lyon']`.

Comment: i was referring to "" not the comma

Comment: But you need the `""` so that the commas in the list won't be treated as field separators of the CSV.

Comment: @Barmar Ohh ok thank you, but when I want to convert from a CSV file into a JSON file the list will not go back to the right form what should I do then?

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the lists after reading the CSV file.

Comment: CSV isn't really designed to handle nested structures, since those are language-dependent. Why not save it as JSON or Pickle?

Comment: *everything in a csv is text*. CSV is a text-based format. What, **exactly** are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have a big project that i may have to convert from csv file into json file and the other way around , the project idea is API that's why i need to know how to do it, if these is any suggestion please let me know @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @Barmar i already know how to save it into JSON but i need to know how to work things around in CSV files that include nested structure

Comment: @Anmar generally, CSV files *are not used for nested structures*, but rather, for tabular, "record" data. In any case, it isn't clear why these quotes are a problem - that is what I was asking, what *problem* are you trying to solve by removing the quotes?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when I'm writing on the CSV file with a nested list , the list is being converted into a string , so when I'm trying to write the content of the CSV file into a JSON file the nested list count as a String inside the json file ,it will also consider the list as a string not a list

Comment: @Anmar again, **it isn't being converted into a string**. **Everything in a csv is text**. That is *how csv's work*. IOW, removing those quotes *won't do anything to solve your problem, because they aren't the source of your problem*.

Comment: The problem seems to be *how to recover your object from the text*. What you should *probably do* is *not use the csv format at all*, but as other's have pointed out, you can use `ast.literal_eval` (or just `eval`) to *parse that string*. But again, you really should just use something like HDF or even `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` option to `df.to_csv()` to disable quoting. But you also need to use the `escapechar` option to specify an escape character that will be printed before `,` characters in the lists.

```
import csv

df.to_csv("data.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
```

The resulting CSV file will look like:

```
,countrey,cities,time_visited
0,france,['paris'\, 'lyon'],4
1,germany,['Munich'\, 'Frankfurt'],9
```

You need either quotes or escapes so that the `,` inside the lists will not be treated as field separators. You'll get an error if you try to print a CSV where a field contains a comma and you haven't enabled quoting or an escape character.

Answer (score 0):

when you save as csv, it converts any lists into strings.

To convert it back into lists you can do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["cities"] = df["cities"].apply(literal_eval)
```

You can save it as a pickle file (instead of csv) which will store it as a list.